# C# MySQL Connection - MultiThreading - Cannot connect

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, asynchronous, connection

first everything runs fine. I am running a program with 100 threads each is establishing a database connection. After sometime I get following error message:

> "cannot connect to any of the specified mysql hosts" (Inner Exception:
>   Connection Timed Out)

MySQL Server is running on a windows machine (Win Server 2012).

I have set the mySql connection limit to 10k, but problem still occurs

```
using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
        mConnection.Open();

        using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand("XXX"))
        {
            myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            // DO STUFF HERE
            myCmd.Connection.Dispose();
        }

        mConnection.Close();
        mConnection.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: there is problem in your connectionstring ! which you didnt post

Comment: I think you would do better to make your code async and allow the Task scheduler to handle threads as it sees fit. Creating threads for I/O bound work like database calls is a waste of threads.

Comment: I am running this in an async method. This method is called by a threadPool

Comment: What are you awaiting? Is it Task.Run()? that still consumes a thread and should not be used for I/O bound work.

Comment: I am awaiting a network request inside it

Comment: That's still as  bad as Task.Run as far as tying up threads. When I say "async" I mean async keyword and await keyword, not the generic meaning of asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will solve your problem:

```cs
 using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
     using (MySqlCommand myCmd = mConnection.CreateCommand())
     {
         mConnection.Open();
         myCmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
         myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         myCmd.CommandText = "XXX";

         using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
             while (reader.Read())
             {
                 // DO STUFF HERE
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

You can set the timeout value as you need (take care because the timeout is in seconds not milliseconds).

You also don't need to use `.Close()` and `.Dispose()` if you are using `using () { ... }`.

**Edit:** Updated the answer according to the comments below.

Comment: ConnectionTimeout is readonly. I need dispose and close because mysql uses connection pooling. The using is useless in this case.

Comment: the connection string is correct. This error happens after some time only. Means before I have successful connections!

Comment: @CarlosSantos the `using` is already going to Dispose for you, it is redundant to enclose this in a `using` block and then call Close() and also Dispose(), which calls Close() itself. But this is not the reason for your problem at all.

Comment: Yes that not really helps me :(  But trust me if I do not dispose the connection at the end of the using, the connection will not be closed. I have tested this... I had many open connections. Normally you are right but in this case the using does not behave like normal

Comment: @CarlosSantos I don't know what you mean exactly, there is no possible way the `using` block does not take care of the connection and the command. And connections are not actually closed on the server, "closing" a connection just returns an open connection to the pool so it is efficiently available for the next MySqlConnection.

Comment: Do you really need to create the connection over and over again?

Comment: I have different threads. Max 100 threads at a time, because this is the default threadpool limit. Each thread has to create a database connection to  insert data into a table. I cannot use a shared connection in this case

Comment: even without any mysql command I get these errors after time... Maybe its a mysql server issue?

Comment: Could you add a try catch for `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex` and then get the error code (`ex.Number`)?

Comment: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException Number 1042

Comment: Error code 1042 means that your hostname couldn't get resolved. Could you try to use the ip of the server instead of the hostname?

Comment: Do you know how many threads are able to connect before the errow appears?

Comment: What did you set as max allowed connections on you mysql server?

Comment: Could you also post you my.cnf file (replace things  that you don't want us to see) so that i can try to reproduce the error.

Comment: Was this resolved? I am having same issues and not sure how to resolve this.